# Remove write protection in SD card

Tags: linux, windows

I have an old SD card that I previously used to store software for an outdated education program. Since it is no longer useful for that purpose, I wanted to repurpose it for my personal use. However, when I tried to format the SD card on my Windows 11 laptop using various methods such as the file explorer and command prompt, none of them worked. Upon further research, I discovered that these SD cards are write-protected, meaning I cannot modify their contents. I learned that it may be possible to remove the write protection by modifying the CSD Register of the SD card. I need assistance with this issue.

[sd card image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g7Hkn.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is usually quite difficult to overwrite the CSD register on your SD card and given the time involved and the inherent risk of destroying the card, you're just better off buying a new SD card.